# Why method invoke return null for method put from proxied Map

Tags: java, dynamic-proxy

There is a problem when method invoke is called for the method-
 'V put(K key, V val)' from proxied Map it returns null.
But for the method - V get(K key) it is all right.

See code example

```
package com.dynamic.proxy;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class LogHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private final Object target;

    public LogHandler(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Start");
        Object o = method.invoke(target, args);
        System.out.println("Finish");
        return o;

    }
}

-----
package com.dynamic.proxy;

import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LogHandler logHandler = new LogHandler(new HashMap<>());
        Map<Integer, String> map = 
        (Map) Proxy.newProxyInstance(logHandler.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{Map.class},
                logHandler);

        System.out.println(map.put(0, "value-0")); //null
        System.out.println(map.get(0));            // value-0
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a standard return value for a Map - if the key you are putting did not exist then return null. What are you expecting to get returned and why?

Answer (score 2):

To quote [the documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-), `Map#put` retruns "the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key". Since this is the first time you introduce the key `0` to the map, the return value of `put(0, "value-0")` is indeed `null`. You would get the same result if the map wasn't proxied.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected - put returns the previous value on the map, or null if it doesn't exist

See from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-):
Returns:
the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key.

Comment: Thank you, it is really expected